ViewContainerRef.createComponent() renders component after container
I have a component template:
<div #wrapper></div>

In my .ts code I have:
@ViewChild("wrapper", {read: ViewContainerRef}) wrapper:ViewContainerRef;
.
.
.
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.wrapper.createComponent(SomeComponent);
}

I want to make an instance of SomeComponent and add it to #wrapper div.
All works as expected except for SomeComponent is being rendered after <div #wrapper></div> and not as its child (which I would expect).
What am I missing?
How to render SomeComponent within div?

This is the expected behaviour, there's no "clean" way to do what you want but you can try this :  How to dynamically create component inside child component in Angular?

@TibèreB. yes, that's what I ended up doing: getting a reference of adiv element and apending a components element as a child (but using renderer).

can't you use <ng-container #placeToRender> inside a div as a place to render?

@Andrei Perhaps. How would I do that? In particular, how would I get the reference to it from the code and how would I apply component to it dynamically?

Andrei's solution is to add an ng-container element isinde of the div where you want to create the component, the template from your example would become : <div><ng-container #wrapper></ng-container></div>

@TibèreB. ok, I see. Is there any particular gain with that approach? I mean, it seems the mechanism of getting the reference and adding component to the element would be the same with the only difference that now it adds to ng-container instead of div. Or am I missing something?

We are not replacing the div for an ng-container, an ng-container can be used to apply structural directive but will not by itself add any element to the DOM. The problem that you have here when you use the createComponent function is that the component gets created as a sibling instead of a child, so we can just add an ng-container inside of the div element and now, the created component will be a direct child of the div element, this avoid using the Renderer2 and the nativeElement which bypass Angular's encapsulation.

@TibèreB.interesting. What viewRef would then be used to createComponent?
